# Turning on encryption on SandForce controllers in OCZ SSDs

Tags: cryptography, solid-state-drive

I have an OCZ Agility 3 SSD. This SSD runs the SandForce 2281 controller ([PDF spec sheet](http://www.ocztechnology.com/res/manuals/OCZ_Agility3_Product_sheet.pdf)) which supports native encryption. This is especially useful since the controller performs data compression for superior performance and software-based full disk encryption will defeat this purpose.

Does anyone know how I can use the on-disk encryption on the SSD which I run on an early 20111 MacBook Pro?

Comment: I can't find the word `encryption` anywhere in that PDF.

Comment: This is more of a system hardware question, so it probably belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1):

I contacted OCZ for the answer to the same question, the sandforce 2 drivers automatically encrypt the drive's information as it is writing. Therefore to secure the information you just need to add a password to the drive to prevent anyone from being able to install and use the controller to simply read/decrypt the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Self-Encrypted Drive (SED) features of your device on you laptop at this moment.

Every SED device always encrypts all data on-the-fly. What you actually need to do to protect your data on such device is to enable device locking. SandForce controllers allows to implement ATA Security protocol to control it. Unfortunatelly Apple's EFI doesn't implement ATA Security for locking device. What is more, it freezes ATA Security commands on the drive during initialization.